# How do efficiently store child and parent relation in a map retrieved from a nested SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, map

I've got the following query:

```
List<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Type_Reference__c FROM Cases__r) FROM Order WHERE Id IN :orderIds];
```

and I need to store that information in the following map:

```
List<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>> orderToCaseMap = new List<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>>();
```

So, essentially, storing Order Id in the `Id`, `Type_Reference__c` in the `String` key, and the case list in the `List<Case>` value.

The business scenario, (just in case there is a better way of doing this): Whenever a case is created and linked to an order, we populate a picklist value on the case (`Type Reference`) - if a case with that specific type reference already exists, we don't wanna create a duplicate case

So far I have tried

```
List<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>> orderToCaseMapping = new List<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>>();
Map<String, List<Case>> caseMap = new Map<String, List<Case>>();
List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();

        for (Order ord : orderList) {
            for (Case cs : ord.Cases__r) {
                caseList.add(cs);
                caseMap.put(cs.Type_Reference__c, caseList);
            }
            orderToCaseMapping.put(ord.Id, caseMap); // not sure about this part
        }
```

But it's ugly as heck and won't compile

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where you have stuck?

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it went wrong

**Problem #1**

```
List<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>> orderToCaseMap = new List<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>>();
```

It Should be a map of ( id, map of (String, list of cases)), like below:

```
Map<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>> orderToCaseMapping = new Map<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>>();
```

**Problem #2**
You are not initializing a new `List<Case>` (or cloning and clearing) for each iteration of the loop over Order. This would cause all Orders to contain all Cases (instead of just the Cases related to a given Order).

**Problem #3**
You need to initialize the new map `Map<String, List<Case>>` for each order.

Resolving all those issues, the final code will be like below.

```
Map<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>> orderToCaseMapping = new Map<Id, Map<String,List<Case>>>();
for (Order ord : orders) {
    Map<String, List<Case>> caseMap = new Map<String, List<Case>>();
    for (Case cs : ord.Cases__r) {
        if(String.isNotBlank(cs.Type_Reference__c)){
            if(!caseMap.containsKey(cs.Type_Reference__c)){
                caseMap.put(cs.Type_Reference__c, new List<Case>());
            }
            caseMap.get(cs.Type_Reference__c).add(cs);
        }
    }
    orderToCaseMapping.put(ord.Id, caseMap);
}
```

Please mind that the keySet of the map is **case sensitive**.

Comment: The other missteps in OP's original code are 1) Not initializing a new `List<Case>` (or cloning and clearing) for each iteration of the loop over `Order`. 2) Calling `put()` inside the inner loop over `Case`. #2 isn't s big problem, just a waste of resources. #1, however, would cause all `Orders` to contain all `Cases` (instead of just the `Cases` related to a given `Order`). The code in this answer _does_ address both of those.

Comment: @DerekF Thanks for pointing out, I couldn't figure out how to mention that in words. I will update this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I guess you can't have an outer <List> type..

Comment: @erikvm you can have, but list can have only one argument like `List<Type>` but you were trying `List<Type, Type2>`. but this works with the map: `Map<Type, Type2>`. Also both the type can be the same as well.